# Can't remove item of Kendo web grid with knockout

Tags: user-interface, web, knockout.js, grid, kendo-ui

I've a Kendo web grid combined with knockout. The last column of the grid contains a button to remove the row. But the parameter of the removeItem method

```
this.removeItem = function (item) {
        this.FilteredClients.remove(item);
    }.bind(this);
```

gets the wrong value.

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/zeQMT/93/

What's missing?

BTW. I don't want to use row templates because I want to set the columns titles by myself.

Comment: The 'kendoGrid' custom binding may not be working/coded properly. In your jsFiddle code, the "item" passed to your removeItem method is the ViewModel object.  I also tried $parent, $root and $data.  They are either undefined or point to the ViewModel.  I don't think the kendoGrid is setting the binding content properly (but this is from a guy who has never written a custom binder nor looked at the kendoGrid binder...)

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using the row templates, then it is not seamless to bind in this manner. There are a couple of pretty easy ways though that you can handle the click on a button in the cell, find the data item associated with that row, then locate the view model item.

For example, you can bind your columns like:

```
   columns: [
                { field: "id", title: "id"},
                { field: "name", title: "name"}, 
                { command:[{text: "x", click: removeItem}]}
            ]
```

Then, your `removeItem` function would need to locate the appropriate view model item like:

```
this.removeItem = function(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    if (dataItem && dataItem.id) {
        self.items.remove(function(item) {
           return item.id === dataItem.id; 
        });
    }
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EpkPy/

If you want to keep your view model code cleaner (avoid referencing events/elements in it), then you could attach a handler that locates the item and then call into the view model.  This would be my preference.

Something like:

```
   columns: [
                { field: "id", title: "id"},
                { field: "name", title: "name"}, 
                { command:[{text: "x", className: "btnRemove" }]}
            ]
```

Then, attach a handler unobstrusively to the button like:

```
$("#myGrid").on("click", ".btnRemove", function(e) {
    var widget = $("#selectedServices").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = widget.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    if (dataItem && dataItem.id) {
          vm.removeItem(dataItem.id);
    }
});
```

The `removeItem` method on your vm would then just take in the id like:

```
this.removeItem = function(id) {
    self.items.remove(function(item) {
        return item.id === id; 
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/AwX5N/

Comment: Nice example.. Hi @RPNiemeyer, I have a same issue with this but my source come from nested array, do you have sample for nested array?

Comment: @RamonCruz - added an answer to the other question. sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/L26q8/

Comment: using rowTemplates, yeah!